# NestJS and MySQL - How to insert a default password into Users table that uses bcrypt hash?

Tags: mysql, nestjs, bcrypt, typeorm

I have a simple web application that allows for registering of new users using bcrypt to store the password.

My TypeORM User entity looks like:

```
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column({
        type: 'nvarchar',
        length: 256,
        nullable: false,
        unique: true,
    })
    username: string;

    @Column({
        type: 'nvarchar',
        length: 256,
        nullable: false,
    })
    password: string;

    @BeforeInsert() async hashPassword() {
        this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10); // salt rounds
    }

    async comparePasswordAsync(attempt: string): Promise<boolean> {
        return await bcrypt.compare(attempt, this.password);
    }
}
```

The creation of new users using an exposed endpoint works fine. Now, let's say I want to ship the product with a default admin account in the User table.

How do I write a migrator such that it adds a default username and password for an admin account?

Here is my migrator:

```
export class UserTable1594240665620 implements MigrationInterface {
    public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        // Create the user table
        await queryRunner.query(`
            CREATE TABLE user(
                id VARCHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                username VARCHAR(256) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
                password VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
            );`);

        // Add the default user
        await queryRunner.query(`INSERT INTO user(id, username, password)
             VALUES (UUID(), 'defaultAdmin', ????);
        `);
    }

    public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE user`);
    }
}
```

What do I put into the `???` in the above code in order to save the hashed default admin password?

Comment: Itf you do this, you need to force them to choose a new password on first login.  Also force them to do this before anyone else can use the site / application.  Many applications and devices have been hacked over the years because users never changed the admin password and it was the same for all or from a small fixed set.

Comment: @DaveS Will do. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well hello again (I just answered another one of your questions).

Per Dave S comment, beware of the security implications of having a default user...

As another security comment, you should also use both a salt and a hashed password, never a hash on its own. Save both the salt and hash in your user entity.

Be sure to use `bcryptjs` library over `bcrypt`. They work identically but you won't have deployment issues with `bcryptjs`.

```
import * as bcrypt from 'bcryptjs'

// ...

const password = 'example'
const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt()
const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt)
```

As for cleanly inserting values, note that you can get a lot more out of your queryRunner in TypeORM, e.g.:

```
queryRunner.manager.createQueryBuilder()
```

Check the docs for the Query Builder but this is a pretty straightforward API, e.g.  `.insert().into(...).values({ ... }).execute()`.

Refer to the docs at https://typeorm.io/#/insert-query-builder

You can generate a fresh salt as well as a hash for your default password and then insert those values as part of inserting your default user.

Cheers!

Comment: I didn't know about the query builder nor `bcryptjs`. Thank you!